# NativeScript Angular upload file from phone FileSystem

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I'm trying to upload a file from a phones file system on the press of a button using the angular version of typescript.

On the press of the button the users phone 'file explorer' equivelent should open and allow the user to select a file to be uploaded to the app.

I have been following the Guide on the page https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/file-system#file-usage and I have copied the import statement under the 'Usage' title and the type script under 'Get or Create' a File With Path. However on press of the button nothing appears to be happening and I have checked that the buttons on click is working by printing a message to the screen. Relevant Code:

```
import { knownFolders, Folder, File } from "tns-core-modules/file-system";
declare var vm;
declare var path;

loadMedCert() {

    const documentsFolder: Folder = <Folder>knownFolders.documents();
    const filePath: string = path.join(documentsFolder.path, "FileFromPath.txt");
    const file: File = File.fromPath(filePath);

    // Writing text to the file.
    file.writeText(.vm.get("textContentToBeSaved"))
        .then((result) => {
            // Succeeded writing to the file.
            file.readText().then((res) => {
                // Succeeded read from file.
                vm.set("isContentSaved", true);
                vm.set("savedContent", res);
                console.log(`File content:  ${res}`);
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.stack);
        });

}
```

Comment: You could simply use [nativescript-mediafilepicker](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-mediafilepicker) plugin, use custom option to allow picking file with specific extension.